# C++ 17: Deduce signature from Callable in a template

Tags: c++, c++17, signature, callable, template-argument-deduction

If and how is it possible to deduce the signature type from any callable in C++17?
Snippet:

```
template <typename T>
struct MyFunction;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct MyFunction<R(Args...)>
{
};

template <typename Callable>
auto deduceSignature(Callable&& c)
{
    // using Signature = ???;
    // return MyFunction<Signature>{ ???};}
}
```

I would like to use use class template argument deduction in the `return` statement.
In client code I want to write this then:

```
std::int8_t freeFunction(std::int8_t x)
{
    return x;
}

auto c1 = deduceSignature(&freeFunction);
auto c2 = deduceSignature([](std::int8_t x){
    return x;
});
```

Comment: `std::function` does this automatically. The easiest is probably to use that in an undeduced context. Something like `decltype(std::function{std::declval<Callable>()})`

Comment: Can you provide an example? If I put this line into deduceSignature, then I get "error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct utils::memoize::MyFunction<std::function<signed char(signed char)> >’"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`std::function` can be constructed from any callable, and can deduce the signature (since c++17). We can use this to make a type trait that extracts the signature.

```
#include <functional>

template <typename T>
struct get_signature;

template <typename R, typename... Args>
struct get_signature<std::function<R(Args...)>> {
    using type = R(Args...);
};

template <typename Callable>
auto deduceSignature(Callable&& c)
{
    using Signature = typename get_signature<decltype(std::function{c})>::type;
}

int main() {
    deduceSignature([](int a){return 5;});
}
```

Comment: Notice that the callable should not have overloaded `operator()` or templated one. (else anyway signature would be ambiguous).

Comment: Great thx.Just one question: what makes this special for C++17? Does this not work with C++14?

Comment: @Juergen, [CTAD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template_argument_deduction), I guess.

Comment: @Juergen CTAD as Evg mentioned. You can make it work in c++11 as well, but you need more boilerplate. Usually the approach there is to take the signature of the objects `operator()` which works on functors and lambdas. Then you need a separate specialization to deal with function pointers.